# how to call activity in one package to another in android

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent i=new Intent(this,com.sms.sms.SmsSync.class);// error at this line
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you elaborate on your issue?

Answer (score 2):

`this` is possibly referring to an `OnClickListener`, reference your class name instead and let's *assume* that SmsSync is in the same package:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmsSync.class);
```

Comment: In case of `implements OnClickListener` over Activity `this` is not going to refer `OnClickListener` of view.

Comment: You are right, I wrote "possibly referring" for this exact reason. This is an educated guess since there is so little to work with... For all we know user1871746 may have simply forgotten to import the Intent class. :)

Comment: yeah. I just add this comment for the sharing info purpose only. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SmsSync.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityname.this, SmsSync.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Following link will help you to start:

[Android Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your activity in different package so you have to register your acitivity with package name in `AndroidMenifest.xml`

like this

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.sms.sms.SmsSync"/>
```

After then you can start acitvity as normal activity.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(your_context, SmsSync.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call one activity from another which is in different package or application, then you need to use as the following.

**startActivity(new Intent("com.sms.sms.SmsSync.class"));** // Fully qualified class name.

While in the manifest file, you need to register this activity as follows.

```
<activity android:name=".SmsSync"
android:label=”SmsSyncActivity”>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="net.learn2develop.SmsSync" />
<category android:name=”android.intent.category.DEFAULT” />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You might need to mention this `“android.intent.category.DEFAULT”` to the intent filter, so that this activity can be started by another activity using the startActivity()
method. Hope this helps.